How can I split and add new row?
I have two rows:
  1.  [{'name': 'xxx', 'admin-status': 'up'}, {'name': 'zzz', 'admin-status': 'down'}]
  2.  {'name': 'yyy', 'admin-status': 'up'}

I want split row if it is list(first) row and add new row.
result:
1. {'name': 'xxx', 'admin-status': 'up'}
2. {'name': 'zzz', 'admin-status': 'down'}
3. {'name': 'yyy', 'admin-status': 'up'}

DataFrame:

data = [
    "[{'name': 'xxx', 'admin-status': 'up'}, {'name': 'zzz', 'admin-status': 'down'}]",
    "{'name': 'yyy', 'admin-status': 'up'}"
]

df= pd.DataFrame(data,  columns=['data']))

I try chatgpt and other but I can not find solution.

Use ast.literal_eval to convert the strings to lists, with a custom function to ensure having a list, then explode:
from ast import literal_eval

def f(s):
    x = literal_eval(s)
    return x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]

df['data'] = df['data'].map(f)

out = df.explode('data')

Output:
                                      data
0    {'name': 'xxx', 'admin-status': 'up'}
0  {'name': 'zzz', 'admin-status': 'down'}
1    {'name': 'yyy', 'admin-status': 'up'}

Alternatively, if you want to keep strings, you could strip the [] then split with a regex and explode:
out = (df
   .assign(data=df['data'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', *(?={)'))
   .explode('data')
)


and also please write, second step :)  --> key convert columns and value in variabels. as I know it is normalaizer..

@Lucas in this case you want to use pd.json_normalize(df['data'].map(f).explode())

I receaved error: "ValueError: malformed node or string: ",

@Lucas this means one of your strings is an invalid representation of a dictionary/python object. How to solve this depends on the exact string. Have you tried my alternative approach with a regex?

Thanks, I solved this error by if condition. Some record was differences.
